# Redirect the standard input and output of .net program

Tags: c#, .net, python

I am writing a test script for a C/S system in python. And right now, we only have a test client written in C#. It is a command line based client. I want to control the input and get the output of the client in my python script. How could I make it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `subprocess` module as follows:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("cat", stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = proc.communicate(input)
```

The process ends after the last call. If you want to do some input iteratively, you can use `proc.stdin.write`, but you have to call `communicate(None)` at the end to finish the process.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Hi,I know how to start the .net program using subprocess.Popen. But I do not know how to interact with the .net program with Popen. Could you give more details? Thanks.